# Can movies depict minors drinking alcohol?

Tags: united-kingdom, minor, alcohol

Are you allowed to show in your film kids or teens drinking alcoholic drinks? Or is it against the law in the UK?

Comment: Just because an actor *appears* to be drinking alcohol, that doesn't mean they *are* drinking alcohol.

Comment: I hear tea makes a good whiskey substitute on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it isn't illegal in the UK to have under 18s **ACT** drinking alcoholic drinks, ensuring you are giving them non-alcoholic drinks. For most acting, actors will drink a non-alcoholic substance that looks like beer, since we wouldn't want drunk actors.

On the 8/6/16 in a Soap known as Coronation Street a 16/17 (I can't remember which) year old boy had a hangover which you get from drinking too much. On the 6/6/16 he was handing beer (while near 2 adults) and at the end of the scene he takes a couple of bottles after being denied some beer to drink. There have been other instances in the soap where kids have been drinking or attempting to. **So it's legal to have kids acting drunk or acting to drink so long as you give them non-alcoholic substances.**